# Force redirect permanently on RedirectMatch from $_GET url to semantic url

Tags: .htaccess

I am doing some .htaccess settings to improve SEO with semantic URL's. Currently when you go to the semantic URL `www.website.com/profile/exampleusername` it works perfectly although i am still able to access the same page without any red alarms rining with the pure get request in the url. `www.website.com/profile?username=exampleusername`.
I have tried to user both the redirect and RedirectMatch but i can't get it to work.

Here is the relevant code from the .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?username=([^\s&]+)&buddy_identifier=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&buddy_identifier=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I want to be able to go to `www.website.com/profile?username=exampleusername` and then be redirected to `www.website.com/profile/exampleusername`

Full .htacces

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

        ############# REMOVE FILE EXTENSION #############

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]


    #####

    ######## ONLY ACCESS BY HTTPS://WWW.* AND NO EXTENSION #############
        #commented bcs of dev workspace localhost

    #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^/]+)\.php(\?|\ |$)
    #RewriteRule ^ /%2 [L,R=301]
    #RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


############# INDEX RENAME #############

DirectoryIndex gamingbuddy.php


################### SEMANTIC URL ######################

### URL FOR GAMES.PHP ###

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /games\.php\?game=([^\s&]+)&game_style=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^games/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ games.php?game=$1&game_style=$2 [L,NC,QSA]


### URL FOR PRIVATE PROFILE ###

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?username=([^\s&]+)&buddy_identifier=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&buddy_identifier=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile(?:\.php)?\?username=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I can still access the www.website.com/profile?username=exampleusername which is the part i was asking for. How do you redirect to www.website.com/profile/exampleusername when you go to www.website.com/profile?username=exampleusername

Comment: This rule is for that redirect. Can you show your full htaccess in question?

Comment: I've now added the whole .htaccess

Comment: ok place my updated rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line and retest